# How to specify an "or" in sed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I have a file having data in the following form

```
<A/Here>  <A/There>
<B/SomeMoreDate> <C/SomeOtherDate>
```

Now I want to delete all the A,B,C from the file in an efficient way. I know I can use sed for one pattern

```
sed -i 's/A//g' /path/to/filename.
```

But how do I specify such that `sed` to contain an `or` to deletes all the patterns?

The expected output is:

```
<Here>  <There>
<SomeMoreDate> <SomeOtherDate>
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @devnull I have specified the expected output in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivaylo Strandjev's answer is correct in that it solves the problem when wanting to match single characters. There is a way though to have or when matching longer strings.

```
s/\(\(stringA\)\|\(stringB\)\|\(stringC\)\)something/something else/
```

You can try with somehting like:

```
echo stringBsomething | sed -e 's/\(stringA\|stringB\|stringC\)something/something else/'
```

It is sad that `sed` requires all these backslashes. Some if this is avoided if you use `-r`.

Comment: Yes it do have strings. Can you please illustrate it with the help of a small example

Comment: @JannatArora, second code block is an example how "stringBsomething" is changed to "something else". I just improved the example to have less `(`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed -i 's/[ABC]//g' /path/to/filename`. `[ABC]` will match either `A` or `B` or `C`. You may find [this reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm) useful.

Comment: Unless you lied and your prefixes aren't all exactly one character long; then, you cannot use a character class. The fix is easy, but unfortunately, different `sed` implementations have differen syntax. Try `s%<\(A\|B|\C\)/%<%g` where maybe the backslashes have to be removed in some dialects.

Comment: Also, boo hiss for linking to a tutorial which uses [Useless `cat`s](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) throughout.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU sed, you can say:

```
sed -r 's#(A|B|C)/##g' filename
```

The following should work otherwise:

```
sed 's#A/##g;s#B/##g;s#C/##g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/<[ABC]\//</g" /path/to/filename
```

because it is a special case of 1 char in length changing in the pattern. This is not a real OR

you can use this workaround on limited to POSIX sed

Sample for test purpose

```
echo "<Pat1/ is pattern 2> <pat2/ is pattern 2>
<pAt3/ is pattern 3>
<pat4/ is pattern 4> but not avalaible for Pat1/ nor <pat2
" | \
```

The sed part

```
sed 's/²/²o/g
t myor

:myor
s/<Pat1\//²p/g;t treat
s/<pat2\//²p/g;t treat
s/<pAt3\//²p/g;t treat

b continu

: treat
s/²p/</g
t myor

: continu
s/²o/²/g
'
```

This use a temporary char as generic pattern "²" and a series of s/ followed by a test branch as OR functionality